# Get data for partial view

Tags: ajax, partial-views

In my main view I have the following:

```
<div id="partial">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Recon/Partial/Partial1.cshtml")
</div>
<div><input type="button" id="partialbtn" /></div>
```

....rest of view

My ajax call

```
  $("#partialbtn").click(function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: "Recon/Partial1",
        type: "get",
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            $("#partial"),html5(result);
        }
    });
```

My Controller

```
       public ActionResult Partial1()
    {
        ViewBag.Test = "From Controller";
        return View("~/Views/Recon/Partial/Partial1.cshtml");
    }

})
```

When I click the button I get a javascript error that says "Function Expected".  I am basically, for now, just trying to test the concept of reloading a partial view without affecting the rest of the view.  Not sure what I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure what was wrong but when I modified my AJAX call to
    $('#partialbtn').click(function () {
        var url = "/Recon/Partial1";
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $("#partial").html(data);
        });
    });

it is now working fine.